# Querying for many relations of type "hasMany" in one query - lot of rows returned

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have model `User` and models `Profile`, `Comment`, `Tag`, `Friend`.
There exist following relations between models:

```
User.hasMany(Profile)
User.hasMany(Comment)
User.hasMany(Tag)
User.hasMany(Friend)
```

by `hasMany` relation I mean that for example `Profiles` table has FK column on `Users.id`.
I want to fetch `User` by user id and also fetch all associations. I use ORM to do this and it generates following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Users" users
LEFT JOIN "Profiles" profiles ON profiles."UserId" = users.id
LEFT JOIN "Comments" comments ON comments."UserId" = users.id
LEFT JOIN "Tags" tags ON tags."UserId" = users.id
LEFT JOIN "Friends" friends ON friends."UserId" = users.id
WHERE users.id = 1
```

The problem is that rows returned by query are multiplied. So if user has 10 profiles, 10 comments, 10 tags and 10 friends then query will return `10*10*10*10 = 10 000` rows. This is quite a lot and it require time to transfer from db to app and also time for parsing it (and memory too!). So how to avoid such situation? Should I make separate queries to DB? Or there some special trick that will stop multiplying rows by each others?

For now query that I am using returns 73k rows (!) and consumes ~400MB (!!!) before parsing to desired model structure.

---

This especially "escalates" if I have many relations of type `hasManyThrough` (which adds 1 additional join table per relation/association)

Comment: _Should I make separate queries to DB?_ Yes, send four different queries.

Comment: So this is standard approach when fetching such data structure?

Answer (score -1):

Would a union work?

```
select p.id from users u join profiles p on p."Userid" = u.id where u.id = 1
union all
select c.id from users u join comments c on c."Userid" = u.id where u.id = 1
union all
select t.id from users u join tags t on t."Userid" = u.id where u.id = 1
union all
select f.id from users u join friends f on f."Userid" = u.id where u.id = 1
```

Comment: `union` requires same number of columns of the same type

Comment: I'll remove the wildcards